# C++: string.find finds a char in a string only if its on pos1

Tags: c++

I want to find a char (expected_char) in a string (word) by

```
if (word.find(expected_char)==true)
{
    cout << "You got one! It's on pos" << word.find(expected_char);
}
else
{
...
}
```

If my string is e.g. "abcd" and i search for "c" else will be executed; if i search for "b" the if statement will be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is the unsigned type `std::string::size_type`, and it returns either `std::string::npos` (which is the maximum value that `std::string::size_type` can represent) if the character was not found, or the first index of the found character in the string.

Now you are comparing the result of `std::string::find()` to the `true`, which results in integral promotion of the Boolean value `true` to the integral value `1`. Thus, your condition is satisfied if and only if the character `expected_char` is found in position 1 (i.e. when it is the second character in the string).

If you want to check whether the character `expected_char` is in the string `word`, use

```
if (word.find(expected_char) != std::string::npos)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Short summary: `==true` is always a bad idea, and in this case it's even worse than usual.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Indeed. Although in this case even omitting it (and I mean *just* omitting it) would be a disaster.

Answer (score 5):

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and you will understand. Interesting part:

```
  std::string str("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
  std::string str2("needle");

  unsigned found = str.find(str2);
  if (found != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';
```

Answer (score 4):

`find` returns a position, and the special value `npos` if there's no match. You need to test:

```
word.find(expected_char) != word.npos
```

(It so happens that `b` is in position 1, which is also the integral value of `true`.)